# Force two series to have matching indices

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a library function that needs to multiply the elements of two pandas Series objects, call them x and y.  The indices of the series will have the same values: maybe ['A', 'B', 'C'], maybe [3, 4, 7], maybe [True, False], maybe [1.2, 3.8, -4.6].  This will depend on input data.

The index types may be different.  One series might have a CategoricalIndex with categories ["A", "B", "C"], the second series might have a general Index.

The indices are important because I need to ensure that operations like x * y are multiplying the right things together.  Right now they are not, and I suspect the different indices are to blame.

I have called x.sort_index() and y.sort_index() but found that different sorting orders are used when one index is a CategoricalIndex and the other is an Index.  The latter sorts in category order, while the former sorts lexicographically.

One solution would be to swap the index of x in for the index of y, as in y.index = x.index, but  I want to preserve the meaning of index values, and the ordering may be different.

A final twist to make life extra interesting, the indices must consider NaN as a possible value (i.e. the Series that the index describes may have an element describing missing values).  If present there will be only one NaN in the index.

I'm happy to describe approaches I have tried, but everything thus far has come up short, and I'd like experts to weight in if possible.  Thank you.

Comment: please provide at a minimum the input and the expected output ... dont just describe the data

Answer (score 0):

I believe my issue is solved by pd.Series.reindex.